# How to get autocompletion for object properties in pipeline?

Tags: powershell

How can my output object property names be recognized by the next command in the pipeline?

It is very helpful that the PowerShell console will autocomplete property names. Typing in only 'fulln' and pressing TAB will produce 'FullName'.

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Property fulln<TAB>
```

A script I have written produces System.IO.FileInfo objects.

```
PS C:\> (Find-MyFile -Files @('whatiwant.txt','whatelseiwant.txt')[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

However, autocompletion of the FileInfo properties is -not- done for the subseqent Select-Object command.

```
PS C:\> (Find-MyFile -Files @('whatiwant.txt','whatelseiwant.txt') | Select-Object -Property lastw<TAB>
```

What do I need to do to get autocompletion? Does this require creating a .xml file for formatting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **[`[OutputType()]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.OutputTypeAttribute) attribute**, described in the conceptual [about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_OutputTypeAttribute) help topic:

```bash
function Find-MyFile {
  [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo])]  
  [CmdletBinding()]  # Note: No strict need for this, but param(...) IS required.
  param() 
  # ...
}
```

Tab-completion then completes based on the properties of instances of the specified type.

Note that you can have *multiple*, *parameter-set-specific* `[OutputType()]` attributes; here's a (contrived) example:

```bash
function Find-MyFile {
  [OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo], ParameterSetName='File')]
  [OutputType([datetime], ParameterSetName='Date')]
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='File')]
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Date')]
    [switch] $Date
  )
}
```

- However, as of PowerShell 7.3.2, tab-completion then invariably completes based on the *union* of instance properties of the specified types - see [GitHub issue #14909](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14909#issuecomment-786769406).
- That is, even though PowerShell could at least hypothetically know that typing `Find-MyFile | Select-Object -Date` <kbd>Tab</kbd> unambiguously targets the `Date` parameter set, you'll get completion based on the instance properties of *both* `[FileInfo]` and `[datetime]`.

---

Generally, note that **this attribute is in effect an unenforced *promise* to callers**: it is up to your function to ensure that the objects it outputs are actually of that type.

Comment: The `Get-ChildItem` command outputs both `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo` objects. Does it have two (2) OutputType() items?

Comment: @lit, at least it specifies both those types (as indicated by `(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).OutputType`), but note that the source needn't necessarily be _separate_ `[OutputType()]` attributes: you can specify multiple types in a single attribute.

Comment: Is it possible to extend this in general to any object? I am thinking particularly of when a collection is iterated, e.g., `$obj | Where <property> -eq $x`. Being able to tab complete here would be a convenience.

Comment: @Blaisem, you can get it to work if you use the `-Property` target parameter explicitly, but that arguably shouldn't  be necessary. I also just noticed that the answer incorrectly claimed that the parameter-specific output type was honored during completion, but that doesn't appear to be true: completion is seemingly always based on _all_ output types, across all parameter sets. I've updated the answer accordingly.